# setVolumeControlStream not working on ICS

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I have an app which manages phone calls and I need to control the volume of a call when the loudspeaker is on during a call and the volume of the ringtone when a call is incoming.

I'm using:

```
setVolumeControlStream( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC );
```

my Activity onCreate() to control stream by using the volume hard keys.
So far, I can only control the volume when the loudspeaker is on. Moreover, this works fine only on GingerBread devices, but it has no effect on ICS devices.

Is there any known incompatibility? How can I control the ringtone level too? I also tried:

```
setVolumeControlStream( AudioManager.STREAM_RING );
```

but again no effect on both kind of devices.

BTW, I noticed that pressing the hard keys when the phone is ringing changes the "multimedia app volume", not the "ringtone volume" (??).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just ran into this same issue. In my case an empty dialog with no volume meter appears if I have set the control stream and press the volume buttons.